# Specify tick format for plot_date()?

Tags: matplotlib

I'm using:

```
matplotlib '1.1.1rc'
ipython 0.12.1
ipython notebook --pylab inline --no-browser
```

I generate a graph with:

```
xticks(rotation='vertical')
plot_date(ts, percent, xdate=True)
```

where ts is a list of datetimes spanning several days.  I get:

[image]

Note the x-axis; it's only showing the time portion of the datetime.  How do I get it to also show the date?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you take a look at the [standard example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/date_demo_convert.html) for matplotlibs `datetime` if you are following a similar idea then you can instruct the plotting tool how to format the ticks in the line:

```
from matplotlib.dates import  DateFormatter
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter( DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d') )
```

Changing the string to

```
"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
```

will had the time to the x ticks in their example.

Answer (score 1):

Pandas, which is great for time series and data analysis in general, has a wrapper around matplotlib that takes care of most of this for you. In your example you could probably just do:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(ts)  # to get your series into a pandas dataframe
df.plot()
plot.show()
```

It will gracefully handle the date formatting and whatnot.
See http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html